# Unable to save for ad hoc deployment xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I have been unable to save for ad hoc deployment ever since I upgraded my XCode 5 to XCode 6.
I have tried to delete my certificate and upload it back, but it will still return the same error.

Here's the error that I had when trying to save for ad hoc deployment.

[image]

For your information, I am able to build the archive file but not the .ipa. I also checked the code signing and it use the same enterprise distribution profile. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had the same frustrating issue but for me Xcode created an XC: blah blah blah provisioning profile which was really annoying because even though I had the correct provisioning profile created for ad hoc deployment and also installed, Xcode would not see it when trying to export the ipa.

Solution: 
It's very odd and I think it's the same case (please say if it's not) as mine: You have multiple test devices and only a few are selected for the Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile. Am I right?

If so, edit your Provisioning Profile and select All your devices and refresh your account in Xcode to download the latest changes.

Comment: I've checked at the Apple Developer Center and it seems that's not the case. Also is it possible to have a workaround that doesn't require me to edit the setting at Apple Developer Center? since it's my company profile and I'm afraid that I will messed something up.

Comment: codify: I think you are right. Xcode 6 does not find a manually created adhoc profile if that profile only contains a subset of all devices registered online. This really sucks, to be direct.

Comment: This issue is still occurring on Xcode 7 – I was using a subset of devices for an Ad Hoc provisioning profile and got a "An app ID with identifier 'com.xxx.xxx' is not available" when trying to Save for Ad Hoc Deployment.  Only after updating the provisioning profile to include all devices was I able to finally distribute.